# Hive Regular expression - only portion of string needed

Tags: sql, regex, hive

Hi i was trying to extract portion of data from one column in my hive table but the position of character is not in one place

```
select value4,regexp_extract(value4,'*****',0) from hive_table;
```

column value is shown below

```
grade:data:home made;Cat;dinnerbox_grade_Enroll
list:date:may;animal;dinnerbox_list_value
cgrade:made_data;dinnerbox_cgrade_notEnroll
```

I want data from dinnerbox to till end.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a pretty simple regular expression

```
.*dinnerbox(.*?)$
```

Using a non-greedy wildcard, but forcing it to the end of the line makes sure that you always get the dinnerbox at the end.

You want capture group 1

To get rid of the `_` you can use

```
.*dinnerbox_(.*?)$
```

Comment: Thank you Bailey S..It helps :). one more question if i want to select portion of data for example  from  dinnerbox_anytext ...eg:  dinnerbox_grade,dinnerbox_list,dinnerbox_cgrade

Comment: Are you asking how to get rid of the `_`, or how to get the `anytext` from `dinnerbox_anytext` anywhere in the input instead of the end?

Comment: I want a output like eg: dinnerbox_grade,dinnerbox_list,dinnerbox_cgrade. not complete till end of value only portion of data. dinnerbox_anystring

Comment: You want to de-normalize the sql rows?

Comment: No..I am close to the solution- after running select regexp_extract(colname,.*dinnerbox(.*?)$,1) from table and i see the output as grade_Enroll,list_value,cgrade_notEnroll but i want only grade,list,cgrade only. I want to limit the output not till end of my column value

Comment: You could try `.*dinnerbox_([^_]*).*?$`

Comment: I just fixed an error in my previous comment, so if you copied it wtih `[^_]*?`, use the new one instead.

Comment: Also i want add dinnerbox_ to my outputs. my output is like dinnerbox_grade,dinnerbox_list,dinnerbox_cgrade.. i don't want to miss dinnerbox

Comment: Sure, just change where the capture group is by moving the parenthesis `()` around.  `.*(dinnerbox_[^_]*).*?$`